# Can I use AppLovin Max Programmatic Method to show MRec Ads inside a widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, ads, applovin

I want to show MRec ads immediately after loading the ad inside a widget, but it takes time and rebuilds every time that widget is opened.

Code Snippet:

```
void loadAndShowMRecAd() {
    AppLovinMAX.createMRec(mrecAdUnitId, AdViewPosition.centered);
    AppLovinMAX.setMRecListener(AdViewAdListener(
      onAdLoadedCallback: (ad) {
        AppLovinMAX.showMRec(mrecAdUnitId);
      },
      onAdLoadFailedCallback: (adUnitId, error) {},
      onAdClickedCallback: (ad) {},
      onAdExpandedCallback: (ad) {},
      onAdCollapsedCallback: (ad) {},
      onAdRevenuePaidCallback: (ad) {},
    ));
    AppLovinMAX.loadMRec(mrecAdUnitId);
  }
```

then place `loadAndShowMRecAd()` inside a container widget.

Comment: how can you place it in widget its a void function. create separate widget for it and show sizedbox or something else whilst ad is loading and show the ad when it is loaded.

Comment: thank you for your advise. I tried placing it inside a widget but it keeps on showing the MRecAd on the center of the device's screen, not inside the container i wanted it to be shown.

Comment: are you using `MaxAdView` widget?